# Unpublish page when using workflow approval

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, workflow

I get the SharePoint access denied page when I try to use the unpublished option on a list item in the pages library.

We are using approval workflow and publishing, as well as versioning on the pages library.

If I navigate to the version history page, the unpublished version works correctly.

Can anyone advise on this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it is due to the fact that as a result of the postback the browser reloads the page you just unpublished, reverting it to a draft version maybe, and the current user is not allowed to see the draft version of this page because it was initially created by another user?

To confirm, try this:

1. Copy url of the page you want to
   unpublish to notepad or something.
2. Unpublish using the page library
   method.
3. Navigate to the url you
   copied in the first step. Does it give you the access denied message?

I think there is a setting on a document library, that states whether you can see other people's draft documents.

Comment: Another way to verify exactly what is going on is with Visual Round Trip Analyzer, Fiddler or other http trace tool to analyze precisely what traffic is going on and whats in the headers